# APA Citation Followed by in-text reference to figure

Tags: publications, citations, graphics, cross-referencing

I want to provide a parenthetical citation along with a reference to a figure in my text. What is the proper way to format this?

Blah blah blah (Li et al., 1994, 1997) (Figure 1).

Blah blah blah (Li et al., 1994, 1997; Figure 1).

Blah blah blah (Figure 1) (Li et al., 1994, 1997).

Comment: Is the Figure part of your own paper, or part of the paper you are citing?

Comment: A part of a paper I'm citing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the figure is not directly related to the citation, I would be looking to rewrite the sentence to separate the citation and the figure reference. It seems unusual that you would be introducing what is typically your own work (i.e., a figure) and citing a reference at exactly the same point. For example, you could write something like :

> Figure 1 presents the results of ... based on data from Li et al (1994, 1997)

Of course, the way to do this will depend on the details of your content, but I'd generally seek to separate the two elements.

Alternatively, if the the figure is from the citation and you are reproducing it, you could do something like this:

> (see Figure 1 taken from Li et al, 1994, 1997)

Or a variant:

> (see Figure 1 based on data from Li et al, 1994, 1997)